# Find PC storage drive names

Tags: excel, vba

How can I find my PC Drive names and list it out in Excel VBA ?

for example my pc has drives "C:/" , "D:/" and "E:/" is there any way that I can get these letter using VBA ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try-

```
Sub ShowDriveLetter()
    For Each drv In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").Drives
        Debug.Print drv.Path
    Next
End Sub
```

***Output:***

[image]